# Handling negative "s" values for signatures?

Tags: signature

In comparing [these test vectors](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/50980/test-r-s-values-for-signature-generation) to my own results, for tests #2 and #5, I end up with *negative s* values.  My results show that for test #2, `test_s = my_s * -1`, as an integer, yet the hexadecimal representation matches up correctly with the test, while for test #5, `test_s = my_s + curve_order`.  What is the proper way to handle a *negative s* value, or possibly, should I not be getting *negative s* values for these tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us denote `curve_order` by `q`. When computing a signature `(r,s)` it is important to remember that `r` and `s` are meant to represent elements of `Fq` (the field of integers modulo `q`). The formula `s = k^(-1)(e + rx)` is an algebraic expression in `Fq`. So `r` an `s` are not really integers, they are `integers modulo q` (so for example two integers `u` and `u + q` represent the same elements of `Fq`). When implementing a function returning `(r,s)` there is nothing wrong with internally representing these quantities as integers. But when it comes to returning values, you have to decide how you wish to encode the values `r` and `s`. If `s` represents your implementation specific integer, do you simply want to return `s`? or `s + q`? or `s - 3q`? All these answers are the same (simply different encodings) but there is little chance you will match a `test-vector` unless you have a common encoding with it. **When returning an integer** `s` **modulo** `q` **it is customary to encode** `s` **as the unique integer** `s'` **with** `0 <= s' < q` **equal to** `s mod q`.

So for example, when you say that `test_s = my_s + curve_order`, you effectively agree with the test, but have not enforced the usual encoding. When you say that `test_s = my_s * -1`, you genuinely disagree with the test but this is explained by 'standardization' (so make sure that you have `0 <= s < q` and if `s > q/2` replace it by `-s`, but make sure you encode `-s` as an integer within `[0,q)`, which means `s` should in fact be replaced by `q - s`).

Comment: seriously, you are a magnificent human being.  While it is admittedly difficult to understand this, I think I have a grasp of it, and nevertheless do have some working code that produces the same results as the tests, and hopefully thereby uses the same encoding.  I will post my code in order to expose whatever flaws may exist in the logic, or optimizations that could be made to it.

Comment: @BrettDoffing In my opinion, you should avoid cluttering your code with tests `0 <= x < q`. You probably have a method `mod` on your type `Integer` so that `x.mod(q)` always gives you an integer in the interval `[0,q)` (when `x >= 0` it is simply the remainder of the division of `x` by `q`). So if `x.mul(y)` is the normal integer product, `x.mul(y).mod(q)` gives you the product in `Fq` etc. So compute `(r,s)` as usual and before returning it you simply standardize it by calling a method which replaces the signature `(r,s)` by the (valid) signature `(r, -s.mod(q))` when `s > q/2`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  Swift uses a remainder, while my current big integer library is pretty small, with limited functionality, using remainder as well.

Comment: @BrettDoffing if your remainder function for big integers always returns a non-negative integer after dividing by q, then whatever (r,s) you were calculating before, take the reminders instead, and then do a last filtering to standardize before returning signature, and you should match the test vector perfectly :)

Comment: The derivation of this answer is wrong. `s` and `-s` are **NOT equal** mod q. The explanation is: During signature calculations we're multiplying `s` with a curve point `G`. From the resulting point we're **only using the x coordinate** and discard the y coordinate. Because `((-s)*G).x == (-(s*G)).x == (s*G).x` ([negation](https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/notes/elliptic/explicit.html) of a point only inverts its y coord, x stays the same), both `s` and `-s` work interchangeably in the signature. For the canonical encoding (`Low S`) of `s` we're using the smaller value of the two.

Answer (score 0):

While @SvenWilliamson has explained the answer, this is the code I have implemented get my desired results:

```
// As explained in @SvenWilliamson's answer - two integers s and s + q (s2) represent the same elements of Fq
    let s2 = s + q

    if 0 <= s && s < q {
        if s > q/2 {
            print((r, n - s))
        } else {
            print((r, s))
        }
    } else if 0 <= s2 && s2 < q {
        if s2 > q/2 {
            print((r, n - s2))
        } else {
            print((r, s2))
        }
    } else {
        // ??
    }
```